# Uniqueness of the limit on random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Of course convergence in $L^2$ does not imply convergence in $a.s.$ and, equally, convergence in $probability$ does not imply convergence in $a.s.$ or in $L^2$ (without further requirement).

However there is  a sort of uniqueness on the limit of the random variables?

What I mean is, if a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converge to X a.s., does this imply that IF $X_n$ converge also in $L^2$ then the limit has to be the same (namely X)?

Or there is not even this type of relation? Namely $X_n$ could converge to X a.s., and $X_n$ could converge to Y in $L^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_n \to X$ a.s. .

If we also have $X_n \to Y$ in $L^2$, this implies $X_n \to Y$ in probability. Thus there exists a subsequence $X_{\phi (n)}$ converging to $Y$ a.s.. By unicity of the limit, $X=Y$ a.s.

If $X=Y$ a.s., then they are also the same in $L^2$ sense, i.e. $E(|X-Y|^2)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

A quick proof: if $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $E|X_n-Y|^{2} \to 0$ then Fatou's Lemma gives $E|X-Y|^{2} \leq \lim \inf E|Y-X_n|^{2}=0$ so $X=Y$ a.s.